# Is a local constant string in global memory

Tags: c

Is I define a global pointer`(char*)`. Then give an address of a constant string. Is this address  will be freeed. for example:

```
static char *str;    
const char * test()
{
    str = "hello world";
    return str;
}
```

**Q1：** Now is it safe to use the content of the address get by `test` anywhere.
**Q2：** If the `test` is in a DLL. Is it safe to use out side by other program
**Q3：** If it's safe . When I reassign another const string  to variable `str`. Will the old const string be freeed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do the following, you can use the result of foo() anywhere. You should not modify or free it however. It is irrelevant if this code is part of a DLL or a Library.

```
const char * foo() {
    return "hello";
}

// This is identical.
const char * foo() {
    const char *x = "hello";
    return x;
}
```

If you want to be able to modify, you could do something like this. Note that every call to `foo()` will be referring to the same piece of memory because `x` is static. Note that here, you can modify `x`, but you still should not free it.

```
char * foo() {
    static char x[] = "hello";
    return x;
}
```

If you wanted to be able to free the result of `foo()`, you must allocate the space with `malloc()`.

Comment: When I reassign another const string  to variable `str`. Will the old const string be freeed

Comment: No. You only `free()` memory that has been allocated to the heap. `"hello"` in any of the cases above, is not stored on the heap. It's stored in a static piece of memory.

Comment: There is no pointer point to the `"hello"` string in the static piece of memory, if I reassign the `str`. If the old string is still  stored in the static piece of memory, It'll waste the static piece of memory

Answer (score 1):

If only from code perspective, this is safe. But you should make sure in test(), you can only assign a string const to str. If you do like following:

```
const char *test() {
  char somestr[somesize];
  str = somestr;
  return str;
}
```

That's still not safe.

Comment: If the test is in a DLL. Is it safe to use out side by other program

Comment: Yes, it's still safe in DLL.

Answer (score 0):

The assignment to `str` isn't even necessary. Even without it, it would be safe to return the address of a string literal from a function and to subsequently use the string anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

It's safe if you assign a string literal to the pointer, but if you're going to do that it seems like it would be best to leave the function out of the picture entirely:

```
static char str[] = "hello world";
```

Then you could just use `str` like a `static char *` since arrays just decay to pointers.